# Tkinter clear canvas

Tags: python, tkinter

- I am using Tkinter and trying to clear a canvas that will display images using the "clear_canvas" method shown below. While the method is accessible and properly triggered via the "clear" button and will reset the add_images_button_count back to zero the canvas.delete("all") line seems to have no affect for some reason. Help would be greatly appreciated.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
from PIL import Image, ImageTk


# GLOBAL VARIABLES
# INITIALIZE WINDOW
home_window = Tk()
# INITIALIZE IMAGE BUTTON COUNT VARIABLE
add_images_button_count = 0
# INITIALIZE X AND Y POSITION FOR IMAGE PLACEMENT
x = 0
y = 0
# INITIALIZE MAX IMAGE COUNT VARIABLE
max_image = []
# CREATE CANVAS
canvas = Canvas(home_window, width=600, height=400, bg="white")
canvas.place(rely=0.1)


# HOME SCREEN
def home_screen():
    # REFERENCE GLOBAL WINDOW
    global home_window

    # SPECIFY WINDOW SIZE
    home_window.geometry("600x450")

    # CREATES TOP FRAME AND DOESN'T ALLOW WINDOW SHRINKAGE
    header_frame = Frame(home_window, width=600, height=50, bd=5, bg="grey")
    header_frame.grid(row=0)

    # BUTTONS
    close_app = Button(header_frame, text="Close App", bg="white", fg="blue", command=home_window.destroy)
    close_app.place(relx=0.015, rely=0.2, anchor="nw")

    back = Button(header_frame, text="Back", bg="white", fg="blue")
    back.place(relx=0.15, rely=0.2, anchor="nw")

    add_images = Button(header_frame, text="Add Images", bg="white", fg="blue", command=add)
    add_images.place(relx=0.45, rely=0.2, anchor="n")

    clear = Button(header_frame, text="Clear", bg="white", fg="blue", command=clear_canvas)
    clear.place(relx=0.55, rely=0.2, anchor="n")

    next_step = Button(header_frame, text="Next Step", bg="blue", fg="white")
    next_step.place(relx=0.985, rely=0.2, anchor="ne")

    # RUN A NON RESIZEABLE TKINTER WINDOW
    home_window.resizable(False, False)
    home_window.mainloop()


# MAX IMAGE WARNING
def max_image_warning():
    global home_window
    pop = Toplevel(home_window)
    pop.geometry("300x200")
    pop.title("Warning")
    Label(pop, text="Max amount of images reached!").pack(pady=20)
    Button(pop, text="Understood", command=pop.destroy).pack(pady=40)


# ADD IMAGES
def add():
    # BUTTON COUNTER
    global home_window, canvas, add_images_button_count, x, y, max_image
    # SPECIFY FILE TYPES
    filetypes = [('JPG Files', '*.jpg'), ('PNG Files', '*.png')]
    # OPEN FILE EXPLORER AND ALLOW USER TO SELECT PHOTO
    filename = askopenfilename(multiple=True, filetypes=filetypes)
    # APPEND NEW FILE TO MAX IMAGE COUNTER
    max_image.append(filename)
    # CHECK IF MAX IMAGE AMOUNT OF 6 IS REACHED, INFORM USER
    if len(max_image) > 6:
        max_image_warning()
        return
    # FIRST CLICK
    if add_images_button_count == 0:
        # START POSITION FOR IMAGE
        x = 0.1
        y = 0.25
        # INCREMENT BUTTON COUNTER
        add_images_button_count += 1
    # NOT FIRST CLICK
    else:
        # IMAGE POSITIONING LOGIC
        # START NEW ROW AFTER THIRD COLUMN
        if x == 0.7:
            x = 0.1
            y = 0.6
        # ELSE CONTINUE TO INCREMENT COLUMN
        else:
            x += 0.3
    # MULTIPLE IMAGES METHOD
    for f in filename:
        # OPEN AS IMAGE
        img = Image.open(f)
        # RESIZE IMAGE
        img_resized = img.resize((100, 100))
        # TK PHOTO
        img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img_resized)
        # CREATE LABEL TO DISPLAY IMAGE
        panel = Label(canvas)
        # IMAGE POSITION
        panel.place(relx=x, rely=y)
        # ASSIGN IMAGE TO LABEL DIRECTLY
        panel.image = img
        # GARBAGE COLLECTION
        panel['image'] = img


# CLEAR
def clear_canvas():
    # REFERENCE GLOBAL VARIABLE
    global canvas, add_images_button_count
    # CLEAR IMAGES
    canvas.delete("all")
    # RESET BUTTON COUNTER TO ZERO
    add_images_button_count = 0


# add_text = tk.Button(window, text="Add Text")
# add_text.grid(row=2, column=2, padx=5, pady=5)
#
# add_logo = tk.Button(window, text="Add Logo")
# add_logo.grid(row=2, column=3, padx=5, pady=5)
#
# undo = tk.Button(window, text="Undo")
# undo.grid(row=2, column=4, padx=5, pady=5)

# RUN HOME SCREEN
home_screen()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`canvas.delete("all")` only deletes canvas objects -- lines, circles, images, etc that were created with the canvas `create` methods. You're not using those methods so these images are not canvas objects.

Since you are making the labels children of the canvas, you can iterate over the results of  `canvas.winfo_children()` to destroy the windows:

```
for child in canvas.winfo_children():
    child.destroy()
```

Comment: Thank you Bryan, you solution worked flawlessly. Much appreciated 